# Which Android keyboard app allows you to send a handwritten text as image?

Tags: android, images, keyboard

Some Android keyboards let the user handwrite something, but the keyboard digitizes the drawing before sending it. On the other hand, many apps allow direct sending of an image or gif.

How can I quickly prevent digitizing, and instead send the handwritten text or drawn image like an image file?

Comment: Also on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252296/44325

Comment: What you are describing is not the expected functionality of a keyboard. The keyboard opens when the app expect characters. A solution is not sending a text message but a picture (like taking a photo of a blank wall or something like that and then writing on it)

Comment: @flavio not true.

Comment: what i mean is that is not the function of a keyboard. you can transfer emojis and other rich content, but an app that transfer images will not open the keyboard as input, it will open an drawing canvas. It make little to no sense to add this functionality on a keyboard :) But maybe someone add it, if a lot of people think it worth the effort of developing one, if it doesnt exists just now.

Comment: @flavio not true, meant is a functionality of the keyboard.

Comment: @flavio - true. Think of it from the _apps_ perspective, it is responsible for handling the input and no app will expect (or can handle) an image from a keyboard. It is also not the app itself which opens the keyboard, instead Android will open it when tapping into a text input field.